# How to trust a certificate in Cordova application for Android?

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, video-streaming, ssl-certificate

I'm building a cordova app where I have to stream video, using html 5 tag, from a secure resource over https, but the video won't play. I came to a conclusion where I should trust the server certificate, so I tried so many approaches and plugins to trust all certificates and other hacks in `CordovaWebViewClient` at `onReceivedSslError`; but nothing work.
So my question is how can I trust a self signed certificate in a cordova app for Android?

Comment: if onReceivedSslError didn't work, I have bad news... As I told you yesterday, change the server certificate. Anyway, are you sure the problem is the ssl? video tag doesn't work well on some android versions

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to stream video on `https` is by installing the server certificate on the android device. Note that I took this solution instead of signing the server certificate from public authority, because my app will be doing calls on a local domain and will be used locally not available on the store.

Comment: hi, did you ever found a other solution for this problem?